# SwiftUI: Getting error when trying to change location Authorisation

Tags: ios, error-handling, swiftui, location, core-location

I currently have this code where I get the user's current location and then display it on a map. And this seems to work fine. But when the user presses "Allow while in use" and then goes into settings and changes it to "Ask next time" my app crashes. And when that happens I get the following error(s)

> Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 1.)

And

> CLLocationManager(<CLLocationManager: 0x600001d84740>) for
> <MKCoreLocationProvider: 0x600002d803f0> did fail with error: Error
> Domain=kCLErrorDomain Code=1 "(null)"

I don't have a lot of experience but I suspect the issue is due to line 3. I think I'm supposed to use @StateObject. But I could be completely wrong.

If its not line 3 it could be from where I have commented `Checking authorization status...` and down. But honestly I don't know

This is the second error/crash i get [image]

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Btw I have added all the necessary "things" to my info.plist

```
struct Home: View{
    
    @State var tracking : MapUserTrackingMode = .follow

     // This line could be the issue
    @State var manager = CLLocationManager()

    @StateObject var managerDelegate = locationDelegate()

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
           
            Map(coordinateRegion: $managerDelegate.region, interactionModes: .all, showsUserLocation: true, userTrackingMode: $tracking, annotationItems: managerDelegate.pins) { pin in
                MapPin(coordinate: pin.location.coordinate, tint: .red)
                
            }.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }.onAppear{
            manager.delegate = managerDelegate
            manager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone
            print("On Appear")
            manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
            manager.activityType = .automotiveNavigation

            
        }
        .alert(isPresented: $managerDelegate.locationPermissionDenied, content: {
            Alert(title: Text("Permission Denied"),
                  message: Text("Please Enable Permission In App Settings"),
                  dismissButton: .default(Text("Go To Settings"),
                                          action: {
                                            UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: UIApplication.openSettingsURLString)!)
                  }))
        })
    }
}

class locationDelegate: NSObject,ObservableObject,CLLocationManagerDelegate{
    
    @Published var pins : [Pin] = []
    
    @Published var location: CLLocation?
    
    @State var hasSetRegion = false
    
    @Published var locationPermissionDenied = false

    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.898150, longitude: -77.034340),
        span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 1, longitudeDelta: 1)
    )
    
    // Checking authorization status...
  
    func locationManagerDidChangeAuthorization(_ manager: CLLocationManager) {

        switch manager.authorizationStatus {

        case .denied :
            // Alert
            locationPermissionDenied = true
            print("Denied")
            print(locationPermissionDenied)
        
        case .restricted:
            print("restricted")
            
        case .notDetermined:
            // Request
            print("not Determined")
            manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        case .authorizedWhenInUse :
            print("Authorized when in use")
            manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
            manager.startUpdatingLocation()

        default:
            print("Default")
        }
        
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error : Error){
        print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        // pins.append(Pin(location:locations.last!))

        if let location = locations.last {
            print("Latitude: \(location.coordinate.latitude)")
            print("Longitude: \(location.coordinate.longitude)")
            self.location = location

            if hasSetRegion == false{
                region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: location.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.001, longitudeDelta: 0.001))
                hasSetRegion = true
            }
        }
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: You aren’t asking for location again. Ask for it as the last line in on Appear

Comment: Thanks, I try asking for the location again as you said. But now im getting this crazy error...(See post) @loremipsum

Comment: The first thing I would do is move all of the procedural code that handles location managers and delegates (everything in `.onAppear`) out into a model object where it belongs.  The only thing in your view should be view code.